# how can I reduce the x axis of the plot in to smaller bins? so that the it does not look clustered

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

[clustered at the bottom - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUcUX.png)
I am trying to plot how the covid cases increase as a cumulative sum over a duration for various countries. So I basically wanted dates on the x axis and count on the y axis. how can I break my axis into smaller bins so that it looks cleaner?

```
date_trend = covid_data[covid_data['type']=='confirmed'].pivot_table(values='cases',index='Country.Region',columns='date',aggfunc=np.sum)
final_trend = date_trend.cumsum(axis=1)
trend_t10 = final_trend.loc[top10.index]
plt.figure(figsize=[20,20])
for index, row in trend_t10.iterrows(): 
    plt.plot(trend_t10.loc[index].index,trend_t10.loc[index].values,label=index,linewidth=2,markersize=12)
plt.legend(loc='best')
params = {'legend.fontsize': 20,
          'legend.handlelength': 2}
plot.rcParams.update(params)
plt.xlabel('Dates')
plt.ylabel('Number of Confirmed Cases')
plt.title('China in comapriso to other majorly affected countries')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoveflow! Take some time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Try using the [semilogy](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.semilogy.html) plotting tool.

Comment: Following up on @gnodab's comment (I also recommend the tour), if you can provide a little sample data it will make it easier for others to replicate your setup and provide useful answers.